# Sum numerical values in excel, ignoring text

Tags: microsoft-excel

If I had cells containing, say,

- Red 4
- Blue 3
- 2
- 1

And I'm trying to sum the values, what formula could I use to derive the correct total, 10. The number will always be less than 10 and the rightmost character, if that helps.

Comment: If the numbers are not all on the right side, and the text is mostly the same, you can use the SUBSTITUTE function to replace text first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is always only 1 digit and it is always on the end:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(--RIGHT(A1:A4,1),0))
```

Some Older versions will require the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when confirming the formula.

Right pulls the right most character and the `--` tries to turn it from a string to a number, if it cannot become a number it will error and the IFERROR will capture that and make it `0`.  Then we sum the whole array.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need a VBA function for summing up all numbers from a range of cells,
even for the case that there are several numbers in the same cell.

The function can look like:

```
Function SumNumbers(rngS As Range, Optional strDelim As String = " ") As Double
    Dim xNums As Variant, lngNum As Long
    For Each elem In rngS
      xNums = Split(elem, strDelim)
      For lngNum = LBound(xNums) To UBound(xNums) Step 1
        SumNumbers = SumNumbers + Val(xNums(lngNum))
      Next lngNum
    Next elem
End Function
```

And may be called by a formula such as `=SumNumbers(A5:B5)`:

[image]

To create the function, save the spreadsheet as an `.xlsm` file,
type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VBA editor,
right-click "ThisWorkbook" and select *Insert > Module*, and
copy-paste the above text inside the editor.
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save the spreadsheet, and then
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to close the VBA editor and return to Excel.